# Why does ZF2 PRG plugins return [fileUploadFileErrorFileNotFound] => File was not found?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, post-redirect-get

I have been adapting this example to my own forms:  http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html

When I add my file using `Choose File` button on my form, and then submit the form, I get this:

```
Array
(
    [fileUploadFileErrorFileNotFound] => File was not found
)
```

And the variable contents of which is printed out the above is this (after form submit):

```
$fileErrors = $form->get('character-ref')->getMessages();
```

What can be the problem?  I kind of have no clue at this point.  I looked at `RenameUpload` filter and a few sites but lack clue at this point.

**My Code where relevant:**

```
class CommissionInputFilter implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{
    function getInputFilter()
    {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

        //this is the filter that is supposed to make 
        //PRG Plugin file upload possible
        $renameFilter = new RenameUpload(array(
            'target' => "./data/uploads/",
            'randomize' => true
        ));

        // File Input - I am not sure if this is the way to do it
        //some examples do not use FileInput
        $fileInput = new FileInput('character-ref');
        $fileInput->setRequired(false);
        $fileInput->getFilterChain()->attach($renameFilter);
        $inputFilter->add($fileInput);
        return $inputFilter;
    }
}


//code inside controller 

public function addAction()
{
    $form = new CommissionForm();
    $tempFile = null;

    $prg = $this->fileprg($form);

    if ($prg instanceof \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response) {
        return $prg;
    } elseif (is_array($prg)) {

        //**************************************************
        //this line below is where I set my input filter for the form
        //the filter that contains PRG Rename pluging supposedly
        //One interesting note is if I *Remove* the line below
        //then the PRG Plugin keeps the file name as it is supposed to
        //**************************************************

        $form->setInputFilter((new CommissionInputFilter())->getInputFilter());
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $output = new CommissionOutput();

            $commission = $output->getCommission($form->getData());
            $id = $this->repository->saveCommission($commission);

            $view = new ViewModel();
            $view->setTemplate('commission/commission/thank_you');
            $view->setVariables($prg);
            return $view;
        } else {

            //********************************************************
            //My Properly-filled out form ends up here with file errors
            //********************************************************

            $fileErrors = $form->get('character-ref')->getMessages();
            if (empty($fileErrors)) {
                $tempFile = $form->get('character-ref')->getValue();
            }
        }
    }
    return array(
        'form' => $form,
        'characterRefFile' => $tempFile
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh well I guess posting about it helps.

Because I found the cause.  Apparently,

1. The form needs a Form Filter properly set up [done that]
2. PRG needs RenameUpload filter set up [done that]
3. Most importantly, the Form Filter must be set up after form creation and before PRG [not done that]

```php
$inputFilter = (new CommissionInputFilter())->getInputFilter();

$form = new CommissionForm();
$form->setInputFilter($inputFilter);
$prg = $this->fileprg($form);
```

Filtering must be set up after form creation and before PRG plugin yay.